# Reset total_sales of product in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By default it will display total sales of product full time, now I want to it reset total sales of product when order status is Processing or Complete ( in WooCommerce => Orders ). it still does not work :'(

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'order_is_status', 10, 1);
function order_is_status($order_id) {
    global $product;
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
    if ( 'completed' == $order->status ) {
        $order -> update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' ); // reset total oder = 0
    }else {
        echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The action 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' does not provide an order id as a parameter.

Comment: it still does not work 
<code>
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'order_is_status', 10, 1);
    function order_is_status($order_id) {
        global $product;
     $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
     $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
     if ( 'completed' == $order->status ) {
       update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' ); // reset total oder = 0
     }else {
      
     }
    }
</code>

Comment: I would check that $product is actually set. I strongly suspect it isn't as this is an action on an order not a product. In this context I don't think a global product makes sense since a single order may be for multiple products.

Comment: From the order you can get the order items. From the order items you can get the products. Also your $post_id is not set.

Comment: My intention is to let customers order a product and show the number of customers who are ordering that product. When I process the order, it resets the order quantity of that product to zero

Comment: I am sorry but this last comment isn't consistent with your original question and requires a different solution which I don't have the time to do. I suggest you ask a new question with the requirement to show the number of customers who are ordering that product clearly stated. Also, your English doesn't quite make sense. It is desirable that your question be logical otherwise your question will just be ignored. So it would be wise to make a massive effort to make sure your question is logical so someone will respond to your question. Good Luck